# How can an ISP append "index.jsp" to a URL I type in my browser

Tags: redirect, browser-cache

My ISP requires me to log in each day by redirecting me to a login page.  Once I've logged in, they present me with an information page with a link to "Go to the Internet".  When I click this, it redirects me to my browser's home page (google.com) but it appends "index.jsp" to the url first.  I can remove the index.jsp and press enter, but not until I clear my cache does it stop redirecting me to google.com/index.jsp.  This has become a daily ritual for me and everyone else in my neighborhood regardless of browser or operating system.  Anyone know how an ISP accomplishes something like this (it seems they are sticking something in the cache someone).  Is there any chance I can do something to fix this?  I've already called the ISP and they told me its a bug in there system and all I can do is clear the cache every day (lame answer!).

Comment: I know it's a crap answer, which is why I'm placing it here! But I'd change ISPs, if at all possible, if mine did this to me; especially after they 'helped'.

Comment: Would if I could.  I live in an apartment complex.  Don't ever get HotSiteNet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the source of the intercept page that appends index.jsp to the URL:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=/index.jsp">
If you are not redirected in 3 seconds <a href="index.jsp">Click Here</a> to redirect.

<!--
Padding to make file large enough so that IE doesn't use its own default error page.
 (( line repeats, removed by stackoverflow poster ))
Padding to make file large enough so that IE doesn't use its own default error page.
-->
</html>
```

The ISP requires re-authentication each day (system resets at about 4 am) and this (I suspect) is the initial intercept page sent to one's browser in place of the page requested.

After interception, it goes to a page of the form *http://((subdomain)).hotsitenet.com/login.jsp?orig=http://((website.initially.requested.this.day))* where one authenticates.

After authenticating regular web browsing works, except if one tries to go to the first page requested that day, *http://((website.initially.requested.this.day))*, the intercept intervenes.

This results, typically, in a 404 error.

For example, say you went to google.com initially, were intercepted as expected, and authenticated. Now if you go back to *http://google.com*, you instead get kicked to *http://google.com/index.jsp* and google sends back an error page.

Verified to occur in Firefox and Safari.

I wonder if they had the intercept page include some code to not cache the page, if that would do it?

E.g.,

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" value="Thu, 16 Mar 2000 11:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Found this about possibly putting the head section at the bottom of the page: 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/reference/article.php/3472881/So-You-Dont-Want-To-Cache-Huh.htm

Alternatively, the line

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=/index.jsp">
```

from the intercept page could be changed to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=/">
```

And they could have *http://((subdomain)).hotsitenet.com/* forward to *http://((subdomain)).hotsitenet.com/index.jsp* server-side instead of in the client's browser.